# How to remotely change a service account password on multiple servers

Tags: powershell, passwords, wmi, credentials, remote-server

I've been searching through the archives here but haven't quite found a simple (ie: something I can understand) solution to my problem.  I am changing passwords on service accounts using powershell and wmi.  I can change the services one at a time across all servers like so:

```
$Service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -computer REMOTESERVER -filter "name='SERVICENAME'"
$service.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"newpasswordhere")
```

As you can see, I can refer to whatever server I want and whatever service on that server. What I'd like to do is the following

1. Provide a list of servers (a text file with "REMOTESERVER1,REMOTESERVER2" or something similar
2. Change the password for multiple services on the same machine that are running under the same credentials. I was able to get a list of mutliple services using -filter "StartName LIKE '%\MYSERVICEACCOUNT'", but when I then try to run the $service.change to update the password, I get an error

> Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'change'.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + $service.change <<<< ($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"newpasswordhere")
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (change:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

It works fine with only one service though

3. Restart services only if they are already running

How can I enhance this script to handle these 3 additional items?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You would want to add a loop to your above script, and you would want

```
    param
    (
    [string]$File
)
$Computer = Get-Content $file

foreach ($i in $Computer){

$Service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -computer $i -filter "name='SERVICENAME'"
$service.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"newpasswordhere")
}
```

You add the Param so you can utilize this many different times, then the foreach loop will run through your code for each computer in your .txt file.

Now this only answers the first part of your question but should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Luke, When I have more than one server that matches the criteria (-filter "name like '%service%'") I get an error.  I switched from name='servicename' because each server may have a couple of services using the same account. Looks like if I'm not doing service.change it will still go through each service. For instance, I can write to a text file each service, but this format doesn't seem to like multiple services on the same server to have their password changed at the same time

Comment: Then I misunderstood what you were asking, so you are looking for all services that are running under "USER" and you want to change all of those services to update the password of "USER"?

Comment: That was my fault. I explained it as a specific servicename. Additional research showed me I could search for servicenames by the user running them.  Yes, I would like to change the password iin the Log On tab of any service running under a specific user. I'm using -filter startname like '%\\name' OR startname like 'name@%'".  That will locate all of the services, but because multiple services on each server it fails. When I filter for services where only 1 exists per server, the script is successful

Comment: alright this makes more sense, I will think about this and get back to you .